# In Oracle shared server mode, what is a virtual circuit?

Tags: oracle

I read that shared server mode allows dispatcher processes to use two new SGA sturctures : queues (request and response) and UGA (which is just PGA "flushed" in SGA)

So with a that, a single dispatcher can handle several client connections.

My issue is I saw an expression I don't understand : "virtual circuit". What does it do and where exactly is it positionned ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a shared memory(in SGA) used by dispatcher for client connection requests and responses.

> In a shared server configuration, client user processes connect to a dispatcher. The dispatcher can support multiple client connections concurrently. Each client connection is bound to a virtual circuit, which is a piece of shared memory used by the dispatcher for client database connection requests and replies. The dispatcher places a virtual circuit on a common queue when a request arrives.

[image]

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/net_arch.htm#NETAG211)

In other words, its a memory where the actual request is stored and shared server can know what it has to serve by reading this memory. For example if a client sends a query lets say `select * from emp`, the dispatcher has to store it **somewhere** so that an idle shared server process can pick it up and process further. The **somewhere** is the virtual circuit.

Comment: But... what's the difference between the virtual circuit and the request queue?

Comment: @Dudoso You'll have to be more precise the context in which that expression was seen.... When you read [virtual circuit](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/glossary.htm#BGBIIDAA) , it seems it's the same thing... Post another question directly or ask JSapkota about it in another comment